# VPS for Tor & I2P - which other services can I safely run on same?

Tags: tor, openvpn, squid, i2p

I'm toying with the idea of setting-up a Tor node (middle/guard) and an I2P node on the same VPS.  I think that should be safe(ish)...

But I'm wondering what other services I could run without it/them compremising Tor/I2P or vice versa.  Obviously I will open up a larger attack surface (which is bad), but I'm thinking more about services that will de-anomize and/or become exposed when running on the same server.

So any or all of these in addition to Tor/I2P :

- SMTP server for receiving mail only
- OpenVPN for my personal use
- Proxy-server for my personal use
- Web-server - possibly with MySQL
- and/or the same for a hidden Tor service

So which are safe and which should I definitively put somewhere else?